# Smooth isotopy preserves orientation

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, orientation

Let $N$ a $n$-dimensional connected manifold and let $h: N \rightarrow N$ a diffeomorphism such that $h$ is smoothly isotopic to the identity map $\text{id}_N : N \rightarrow N$.

It's clair that the identity map $\text{id}_N$ is an orientation preserving map. Using the smooth isotopy relation, how can I prove that $h$ is also an orientation preserving map?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be the volume form, $f_t^*\omega=h_t\omega, h_t:N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.  For every $x\in N$, $h_x:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ define by $h_x(t)=h_t(x)$ is continuous, this implies that $h_x([0,1])$ is connected and an interval. $h_x(0)=1$, this implies that $h_x>0$, if not there exists $t$ such that $h_x(t)<0$, and IVT implies the existence of $t_0$ such that $h_x(t_0)=0$. Contradiction, since $h_{t_0}\omega$ is a volume form.

Comment: Sorry, can you maybe add some details of your proof? I never worked with the volume form and I'm actually a little bit lost...